# How do I get the onclick href="#" in python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
<a href="#" onclick="showZone("gaoland.net")">gaoland.net</a>
```

I want to click on the link from onclick.

I am using python + selenium. Thanks

I have already tested all this but without success

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//href[text()="gaoland.net"]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="#"]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"#")]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick, "'showZone("gaoland.net")'")]").click()
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("gaoland.net"+ Keys.RETURN)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[con**strong text**tains(@onclick, '#')]").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"showZone("gaoland.net")")]').click()
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('showZone("gaoland.net")').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@onclick="showZone("gaoland.net")]').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferred way is `LINK_TEXT`:

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text('gaoland.net').click()
```

or with **WebDriverWait** :

```
 WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "gaoland.net"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

if that does not work, please try xpath or css selector :

1. xpath :

   ```
   //a[contains(@onclick,'showZone') and text()='gaoland.net']
   ```

or

```
//a[contains(@onclick,'showZone')]
```

**css** would be :

```
a[onclick^='showZone']
```

You can use either use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('')` or

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick,'showZone')]"))).click()
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: Thanks u very much its work

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick,'showZone')]"))).click()